# Assigning A List To Another Does Not Sync Them

Tags: python, python-3.x

I saw an article about how assigning a list to another syncs them, in which to this code:

```
a=[1]
b=a
print(a)
print(b)
a=[2]
print(a)
print(b)
```

which is very basic, should return:

```
[1]
[1]
[2]
[2]
```

instead, it returns:

```
[1]
[1]
[2]
[1]
```

which clearly is because the variables do not sync. I wonder why this is happening, is it because there is no sync, or that it just doesn't work on python 3.7.0?

Comment: try `a[:] = [2]`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It works. I would appreciate it if you can put that in an answer, thank you. Also, can you explain the mechanics behind it?

Comment: done. If someone finds a good duplicate for this, please mention it, I'll close instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doing `a=[2]` *creates* another reference, so the link between the `a` and `b` variable names is broken.

To keep the same reference for `a` use *slice assignment* which reuses `a` reference (and is also able to increase/shrink list size if different from the previous value)

```
a[:] = [2]
```

(In your particular case, if you just want to change values for your list, just change elements like `a[0] = 2`)